# discrete maths: prove a function is one-to one and onto

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Hi I just need a bit of help with how to do this question :)

Consider the function f : Z×Z → Z where,
 f((x, y)) = 3x+ 5y for all (x, y) ∈ Z×Z.

(a) Is the function f one-to-one? Prove your answer.

(b) Is the function f onto? Prove your answer.

edit: I just have trouble grasping the concept of onto/surjective

Comment: What are your thoughts?  Can you come up with two pairs of numbers $(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y)=15$, say?

Comment: What have you tried so far? We are usually not supplying proofs in the first place.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Berci said, the equation $3x+5y=1$ for some $x,y$ is key. It immediately gives you surjectivity.

For any integer $z$, $3(xz) + 5(yz) = z$. So the mapping is onto.

Comment: could you please explain to me why this is, i struggle to understand the concept,

Comment: the pair (-3,2) works for this but i'm just not sure what this is showing

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

1. Can you write up e.g. $0$ with 2 different (but specific) pairs of $x, y$?
2. Can you find $x,y$ such that $3x+5y=1$?

Comment: If you find 2 different $(x,y)$ pairs with the same image, then the function is not one-to-one.

Comment: thank you i get it!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

1. Obtain a Bézout's identity for $3$ and $5$ (the general method is through the *extended Euclidean algorithm*, but for this case an answer is obvious).
2. From $3u+vb=1$, deduce that for any $s\in\mathbf Z$, the equation 
   $3x+5y=s$ has a solution.
3. If $3x+5y=s=3x'+5y'$, show that $3\mid y-y'$ and $5\mid x-x'$, and deduce all solutions in integers of the equation $3x+5y=s$ in function of a given solution $(x_0,y_0)$..